# Redirecting non-WWW to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-301, no-www

I hold my website on google cloud with one-click deploy wordpress. GNU/Linux system, Apache. I want to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com. So I update the .htaccess file as the tutorial from stack overflow. It comes the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". I was wondering if there are some redirect rules existed already because when I visit https://www.example.com, it automatically go to https://example.com.

I've tried a lot of rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

How can I troubleshoot? Thank you very much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG2Pj.png)

Comment: What rule are you using? You also need to configure WordPress to use `www.example.com` and not `example.com` (otherwise WP itself is likely to redirect you back again!).

Comment: thank you for your tips. I posted the rules in my question. I tried a lot of rules but same error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Do you use a load balancer?

Comment: I don't think so. Because I just use the one-click deploy wordpress on google cloud by default.

Comment: The first rule you've posted is not only a non-www to www redirect - it also redirects HTTP traffic and _that_ might be the cause of the redirect loop. The second rule should work, however, you are redirecting to HTTP, not HTTPS (that could also cause a redirect loop)?! You should be redirecting to `https` in the second rule. What is the redirect loop you are seeing? What are you being redirected from/to? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? The order of the rules is important.

Comment: Thank you@MrWhite. According to your first tip, I just edit the wordpress address and site address with www url(without editing .htaccess file) . It seems to be going well. I test on a redirect-checker website. It shows as pictures:


**http://example.com/**
301 Moved Permanently
**https://example.com/**
301 Moved Permanently
**https://www.example.com/**
200 OK

So is that all ok now?  Should I do anything else? Thank you